# Meaning of $\sum _{z:z^N=1} z^m$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

In my lecture notes, I came across the following statement:

- Since $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^Nw^j=\delta_{w1}$, we can find that $\frac{1}{N}\sum _{z:z^N=1} z^m= \sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta_{r, mN}$.

My first question is how is that possible, I don't understand how we can find that and my second question (which I think is causing the first one) is what does this sum mean?
$$\sum _{z:z^N=1} z^m$$

Many thanks!

Comment: It means the sum of $z^m$ over all $z$ satisfying $z^N=1$.

Comment: Oh ok I see thanks, and do you know how the statement is justified?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your use of $w$. Since it's an argument of the Kronecker delta, $w^j$ is probably meant to be $\xi^{wj}$ for a suitable unit complex number $\xi$. Can you edit your question to clarify this? I suggest you visualize which complex numbers are summed as the vertices of a regular polygon to understand the subsequent result.

Comment: Hmm, I feel like there is something odd here: it is trivially true that $\sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta_{r, s}=1$ for all $s\in\mathbb{Z}$. However, if you take $m=1$ and $N=2$ then you get $\frac{1}{N}\sum _{z:z^N=1} z^m=\frac{1}{2}\sum _{z:z^2=1} z=(1/2)[1+(-1)]=0$ so the equality does not hold. Did you write this question down correctly?

Comment: @J.G. I wrote it straight how it is on the notes, so I apologise for the possible mistakes but I do not think I can clarify it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation should read
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{z:z^N=1}z^m=\sum_{r=-\infty}^\infty\delta_{\color{red}{rN,m}}\ .
$$
This just says that the sum is $\ 1\ $ when $\ m\ $ is an integer multiple of $\ N\ $, or $\ 0\ $ otherwise. The sum on the left is being taken over the $\ N^\text{th}\ $  roots of unity:
$$
\big\{z\,:\,z^N=1\,\big\}=\left\{e^\frac{2\pi ik}{ N}\,:\,k=0,1,\dots,N-1\right\}\ .
$$
That is,
\begin{align}
\sum_{z:z^N=1}z^m&=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^\frac{2\pi ikm}{N}\\
&=\cases{\sum_\limits{k=0}^{N-1}1=N&if $\ N\,|\,m$\\
\frac{1-e^\frac{2\pi imN}{N}}{1-e^\frac{2\pi im}{N}}=0&otherwise.}
\end{align}

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you very much!